# Outlets breaker all of a sudden tripping?

Tags: electrical, receptacle, circuit-breaker

Just starting tonight, if I plug my power bar into the same outlet it’s been plugged into for two years, it trips the breaker. There are admittedly a lot of things plugged into that power bar but I have never had an issue before, anyone got any ideas? Could the power bar have gone bad or something?

Comment: you can only typically have 15 amps on a circuit which is everything that breaker controls.  is it the powerbar fuse that trips or the breaker on the panel?  ignoring the powerbar do you have any high loads plugged into any outlets that are on that circuit in addition to the power bar?

Comment: Unplug the power and turn it off.  Unplug everything on the power bar.  Plug the power bar back in.  Turn it on.  Breaker trips, it is a bad power bar.  If not, plug other stuff in one at a time.

Comment: Is the breaker a plain breaker or AFCI and/or GFCI? If you are not sure, upload a picture of the breaker.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible that the powerbar has gone faulty. Its much more likely that you have too much plugged in.  Perhaps, shift something to another circuit.